# Set a link in Asp.net to S3 folder

Tags: amazon-s3, subdirectory

I have an S3 bucket and Folders (image and icon folders).  I need to set an anchor (or equivalent) to the files in those folders.   I want just the link to show up on the page and when the user clicks on it, it will download to their local.

I have searched for a solution but was unable to find any.

Thanks in advance.
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this:

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("Key", "secret key", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            S3DirectoryInfo dir = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, "bucket name", "FOLDER NAME");
            foreach (IS3FileSystemInfo file in dir.GetFileSystemInfos())
            {
                UWDocs.HRef = file.FullName;
                //Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
                //Console.WriteLine(file.Extension);
                //Console.WriteLine(file.LastWriteTime);
            }
```

UWDocs is an anchor with Runat="server"